# Does HLF 1.2 service discovery work with HLF 1.1 peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have a network stuck on 1.1 IBP Enterprise with a peer on cloud. I have another 1.2 peer on a different machine on-prem.

I read about the new Fabric 1.2 service discovery functionality, which sounds very handy. As I understand, this will allow me to make requests without explicitly specifying (endorsement) `targets` (please clarify if this is not the case because I haven't found good documentation on how SDK code changes to take advantage of service discovery).

Do I have access to this new functionality if I use the 1.2 SDK client/CLI with a 1.1 peer + 1.2 peer on the same channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19A9-iNe48MB4IZPCt0ygSY9FcOVubyZO/view) to get some background information about the discovery service in general (the first half of it) and also to see how you use it in the node.js SDK (the second half of it).

> Do I have access to this new functionality if I use the 1.2 SDK
>   client/CLI with a 1.1 peer + 1.2 peer on the same channel?

So the answer is - it depends... 
You will be able to see which peers exists, and which peers joined the channel.
However  - the v1.1 peers won't report they have chaincodes installed - so you won't be able to see them in the responses of the endorser queries of the v1.2 peer.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome video! To clarify my question, I was wondering if I am able to use the SDK (it looks to be 1.3?) as shown in the 2nd half of the video to query/invoke my 1.1 peer + 1.2 peer, or if you would suggest I just stick with hardcoding `targets` and make sure to carry out the "Developer's burden"? It sounds like since the 1.1 peers won't report they have chaincodes installed => they won't show up in the of endorser query responses of the 1.2 peer => so it is incompatible and I cannot rely on the service discovery SDK => so I need to just list my peers as `targets`?

Comment: What I really suggest is that you consider upgrading to v1.2 or v1.4 if that is an option.

{quote}                                                
> I have another 1.2 peer on a different machine on-prem.
{quote}
Can't you just create a new peer in the enterprise cloud that is version at least 1.2?
Besides that - your analysis is correct, and the reason the v1.1 peers don't report chaincodes, is because prior to v1.2 they didn't have a reason to do that.

Comment: Upgrading would be great, but unfortunately it seems we are locked on 1.1 (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/enterprise_plan.html#enterprise-plan-about). It also mentions IBP Enterprise does not have Service Discovery (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/v10_application.html#dev-app-api-endpoints). So being stuck is a real shame because we wanted to take advantage of service discovery and private data collections and IBP 2.0 is just around the corner! Oh well, I think we can work around for now though. Thanks so much for your hard work and support.

Comment: You might also want to try the new IBM Blockchain Platform 2.0 beta ... it is based on Fabric 1.4.